# Socket.io websocket not working in Nuxt 3 when in production

Tags: javascript, socket.io, nuxtjs3

I am creating a socket.io implementation in a Nuxt 3 app. The websockets work when I am in development mode but I get this error [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avMj5.png). I am using Nuxt version nuxt v3.0.0-rc.8, here is what my nuxt.config.ts file looks like:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt';

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: [
        'primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css',
        'primevue/resources/primevue.css',
        'primeicons/primeicons.css'
    ],
    build: {
        transpile: [
            'primevue'
        ],
    },
    modules: [
        './modules/socket'
    ]
})
```

Here is what my modules/sockets.ts file looks like:

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import { defineNuxtModule } from '@nuxt/kit';

export default defineNuxtModule({
  setup(_, nuxt) {
    console.log('Socket Read');
    
    nuxt.hook('listen', (server) => {
      console.log('Socket listen', server.address(), server.eventNames())
      const io = new Server(server)

      nuxt.hook('close', () => io.close())

      io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('Connection', socket.id)
      })

      io.on('connect', (socket) => {
        socket.emit('message', `welcome ${socket.id}`)
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', `${socket.id} joined`)

        socket.on('message', function message(data: any) {
          console.log('message received: %s', data)
          socket.emit('message', { data })
        })

        socket.on('disconnecting', () => {
          console.log('disconnected', socket.id)
          socket.broadcast.emit('message', `${socket.id} left`)
        })
      })
    });
  },
});
```

Here is what my plugins/socket.client.ts file looks like

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

    return {
        provide: {
            io: socket
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my app.vue file that has simple button implementation of a socket emit event

```
<template>
   <button @click="sendMessage" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  const { $io } = useNuxtApp();

  const sendMessage = () => {
    console.log('Click');
    $io.emit("message", "new message sent");
  };
  
</script>
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
"private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxi build",
    "dev": "nuxi dev",
    "generate": "nuxi generate",
    "preview": "nuxi preview",
    "start": "node .output/server/index.mjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^3.0.0-rc.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "primeflex": "^3.2.1",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primevue": "^3.16.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.2"
  }
}
```

[Here is a replit playground that I set up](https://replit.com/@anthonyanth/Socketio-Nuxt-3-Production-Error?v=1)

Comment: So, it also doesn't work in dev no? Maybe you need to use HTTPS here?

Comment: It works perfectly in dev mode but as soon as I build the project the websockets stops working and starts giving me an error

Comment: So @kissu I tried upgrading to nuxt v3.0.0-rc.9 and I got a new warning from the console _WARN  autoImports:extend hook is deprecated. Use addImports() from @nuxt/kit or imports:extend with
 nuxt>=3.0.0-rc.9_ .

Comment: Is the address of your production `http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: @ITgoldman Yes the address is http://localhost:3000

Comment: Some ideas: firewall, https, another instance, port taken. wrong environment variables.

Comment: Thank you @ITgoldman. Let me try to implement those points

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem, for some reason Nuxt 3 wasn't executing my socket.io module on startup in production. I created my own solution using serverHandlers (previously serverMiddleware) and here is what I made.

Here is my nuxt.config.ts file

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt';

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: [
        'primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css',
        'primevue/resources/primevue.css',
        'primeicons/primeicons.css'
    ],
    build: {
        transpile: [
            'primevue'
        ],
    },
    serverHandlers: [
        {
            route: '/ws',
            handler: '~/server-middleware/socket'
        }
    ]
})
```

Here is my server-middleware/socket.ts

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const io = new Server(3001, {
  cors: {
      origin: '*',
  }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Connection', socket.id)
})

io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('message', `welcome ${socket.id}`)
  socket.broadcast.emit('message', `${socket.id} joined`)

  socket.on('message', function message(data: any) {
    console.log('message received: %s', data)
    socket.emit('message', { data })
  })

  socket.on('disconnecting', () => {
    console.log('disconnected', socket.id)
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', `${socket.id} left`)
  })
});

export default function (req, res, next) {
  res.statusCode = 200
  res.end()
}
```

Here is my plugins/socket.client.ts

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

//Socket Client
const socket = io('http://localhost:3001');

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    return {
        provide: {
            io: socket
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my app.vue

```
<template>
   <button @click="sendMessage" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  const { $io } = useNuxtApp();

  const sendMessage = () => {
    console.log('Click');
    $io.emit("message", "new message sent");
  };
  
</script>
```

And here is my package.json

```
{
"private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxi build",
    "dev": "nuxi dev",
    "generate": "nuxi generate",
    "preview": "nuxi preview",
    "start": "node .output/server/index.mjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^3.0.0-rc.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "primeflex": "^3.2.1",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primevue": "^3.16.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: It shows me path socket.io not found and it doesn't work. Did you also get the same error? How did you fix it?

Comment: Hi, Can you create a StackBlitz with your code

Comment: can't edit, so i'll just comment, this code won't work unless you add some library that would inject the `$io` client instance or you can just fix it by importing the client `import io from "socket.io-client";` and using it with post 3001 as in the server code `const $io = io("http://localhost:3001");` other than that everything is perfect, it's a smart solution and it's not well documented so it's hard to find.

Comment: Hi @jadinerky. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I had forgotten to add the code to my socket.io-client Nuxt plugin that would inject $io into the app instance. I have added an edit to my answer. Thank you for pointing that out again.

Comment: Hello I am using nuxt.socket.io package but I have the same problem, when building for production the client seems not be able to connect to the socket server (returns 404 page not found). Did you try out this package? Is this the reason you started writing your own? thanks

Comment: Hi @fydata. This is correct. I tried contacting the creator of the repo but to no avail

Comment: I also tried to contact him. Unfortunately he closed the issues pages on his github. There should be a disclaimer that the package is not working with nuxt 3 imho. The problem hat it is not working is because nuxt 3 does not allow the port of the nuxt and the port of socket.io to be the same. Making a nitro plugin with the socket.io code on a different port made it work for me.

Comment: @fydata Yes I think that there should be a disclaimer because I wasted a whole 2 weeks trying to get it to work and waiting for a response.

Comment: hahaa yes me too ar least 8 days! :p Since the maintainer only accepts pull requests as a form of communication I will make a pull request editing the read-me file adding a disclaimer for nuxt 3.

Comment: How can I run this example on the same port as my Nuxt web server?

Comment: Hi @Elektronenhirn so you can't run on the same port as the Nuxt web server, you would have to pick another one that is not currently in use the machine that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

So I managed to fix the error. I am using Webseocket server (ws) rather than socket.io. I have created a server middleware in server/middleware/socket.ts

This middleware utilises the Nuxt server to create a Socket server.

Here is the [git repo](https://github.com/adityar15/nuxt3socket)