# How to create and access Socket IO server in nuxt3

Tags: websocket, socket.io, nuxt.js, nuxt3

Here i will show how to create and access socket io server in newest nuxt v.3, for many developers migration from .2 may be difficult beacause of new features.

Comment: This is a more comprehensive answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73592619/socket-io-websocket-not-working-in-nuxt-3-when-in-production

Answer (score 2):

This will create your socket io server

```js
// modules/ws-server.ts
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
import { defineNuxtModule } from '@nuxt/kit'

export default defineNuxtModule({
    setup(options, nuxt) {
        nuxt.hook('listen', async (server) => {
            const io = new Server(server)

            nuxt.hook('close', () => io.close())

            io.on('connection', (socket) => {
                console.log(`Socket connected: ${socket.id}`)
            })
        })
    }
})
```

Now we want to access socket in front-end:

```js
// plugins/socket.io.ts
import io from 'socket.io-client'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    const socket = io(useRuntimeConfig().url)

    return {
        provide: {
            io: socket
        }
    }
})
```

```js
// Now import module & plugin into nuxt config:
// nuxt.config.ts
//...
modules: ['./modules/ws-server']
//...
```

Here's example of usage in component:

```js
<template>
<button @click="func()" class="bt">
    <slot>Button</slot>
</button>
</template>

<script slang="ts">
export default {
    data: () => ({

    }),
    methods: {
        func() {
            this.$io.emit('event_name', {})
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.bt {
    background: #202225;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: 200ms;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
        background: #272a2e;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly fine as long as I'm running in dev mode, however as soon as I run it as production, it breaks. Any solution to that?