# How to use Socket.IO with NUXT 3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'd like to use Socket.IO with my Nuxt 3 app, so that the Nuxt app and the Socket.IO server share the **same port** and the Socket.IO server **automatically starts** as soon as the Nuxt app is ready.

I've explored five different solutions, but they all have their downsides:

**Solution 1:** Using [nuxt-socket-io](https://github.com/richardeschloss/nuxt-socket-io). Here, the readme refers to a workaround to get the module to work with Nuxt 3 and newer Socket.io version, however the workaround leads to a 404 page as the author of the repo disabled the issues altogether and does not seem to maintain the module any more.

tl; dr: Doesn't work, no support.

**Solution 2:** Using [nuxt3-socket.io](https://github.com/wobsoriano/nuxt3-socket.io). <s>This produces [this](https://github.com/wobsoriano/nuxt3-socket.io/issues/1) error.</s>

Update (January 2024): This module currently seems to work fine in both development and production and is very easy to use. However, I currently cannot get hot reloading (of the socket.io server) to work with this solution, even though nitro reloads when the files are modified. I hope [this issue](https://github.com/wobsoriano/nuxt3-socket.io/issues/13) gets fixed.

[This issue](https://github.com/wobsoriano/nuxt3-socket.io/issues/9#issuecomment-1880195500) suggest a potential compatibility problem, however I was not able to reproduce (this on macOS).

tl; dr: Works good, easy to use, but without hot reloading (of the socket.io server) and might not work on every platform. **(This is my currently preferred solution)**

**Solution 3:**
Using Nuxt middleware to start a Socket.io server like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73606200/5326607).
This approach generally works, but the Socket.io server does not start until the "/ws"-route is requested, so it requires additional client side code.

tldr; Generally works, but Socket.io does not start automatically.

**Solution 4:**
Using a Nuxt plugin with the listen hook like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73592619/5326607). This does exactly what I want, when in development. However, since the listen hook is only called when in development mode and not when in production mode, the Socker.io server does not run when in production.

tl; dr: Works, but only in development.

**Solution 5:**
Having Socket.io on a different port, but using http-proxy, to proxy everything to one port, like described [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/blob/00d2b90ea074d2cc23393610f5ddcb9943421745/docs/2.guide/3.going-further/12.websocket-servers.md).
This seems to be the best solution so far. However, this approach seems to cause longer load times, especially in development.

tl; dr: Works fine, but seems slow.

**Update: Solution 6**
As suggested by users swooshi and Agustin Nuñez, a solution using custom nitro entry files ([like described here](https://github.com/sush1lemon/nuxt-socket.io)), seems to work well. However, as it basically replaces the nitro entries, this workaround probably has to be adjusted every time the nitro version is changed.

tl; dr: Works fine, needs constant maintenance.

**So here comes my question:**
Is there an easy way to get a Socket.io server to automatically start and listen on the same port as the Nuxt app that I'm missing?

Comment: Solution 4? perhaps you meant to say... tl; dr: Works, but only in development

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that solution 1 and 2 doesn't work.
I tried to create a custom module and it worked perfectly in the dev env but wouldn't work during build.

Lastly I tried swooshi's solution (https://github.com/sush1lemon/nuxt-socket.io) and It worked at first try in both dev and prod so you should follow his example.

Comment: This solution does indeed seem to work, however it's currently causing other things to break on my project, which I'm still trying to solve. (NUXT Hot Reloading not working, frequent random reloads, frequent ECONNRESET)

Comment: Does this happen when you build the project? or when you run "dev" ? lmk If I can help you, because to me it has been working pretty well

Comment: This bug was since fixed. The workaround is working currently, however, it's still a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a good idea but can try to create your own nitro preset and entry files, just like what i did here https://github.com/sush1lemon/nuxt-socket.io

Demo: https://nuxt-socket.onrender.com/

Comment: This solution does indeed seem to work, however it's currently causing other things to break on my project, which I'm still trying to solve. (NUXT Hot Reloading not working, frequent random reloads, frequent ECONNRESET)