# Nuxt3: pushing updates from server to all interested clients?

Tags: socket.io, nuxt3

Does Nuxt3 support anything that allows the server to push updates? I have a web application that uses the `server/api/` route for its rest API and a web frontend getting the data from there. In some routes, when I receive a `POST`, I would like to inform all clients about the new data.

Typically I'd use socket.io for this, but I'm wondering if Nuxt3 supports something like this out of the box and if not if there are any examples how to get socket.io running in this setup. All examples I can find use express for routing, but Nuxt3 sets all of this up under the hood and, as far as I know, does not use express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR: Not yet, but hopefully soon.

As of right now, Nuxt 3 doesn't offer a way to do this out of the box. [The server framework it uses under the hood is Nitro](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/server-engine), which doesn't quite yet support websockets, at least not officially.

There are some attempts get socket.io working documented in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75970500/how-to-use-socket-io-with-nuxt-3), but none of them seem to work well, if at all.

Based on what I can see in [this issue](https://github.com/unjs/nitro/issues/678) and [this PR](https://github.com/unjs/listhen/pull/128), there's recent work being done by the team maintaining Nitro (and h3, which *it* uses) to try to make setting up websockets possible and easy.

I've been waiting for this capability as well, and I hope it's not long before it's released.